# Which is easier to learn - Google Cloud or AWS, with the main use case being Redshif/BigQuery + small data pipelines.

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, data-warehouse

Looking at building a small-data warehouse, so don't need much scaling - just flexibility & ease of building ETL pipelines and minimal maintenance.

Currently we are looking at a relatively simple architecture with Google App Engine handling the ETL into BigQuery, but I'm wondering if RedShift + EC2 would be easier to learn? We haven't worked with either cloud as a team.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good question for StackOverflow as it can only be answered with opinions.

However, I will try to help as I know the four major clouds very well (AWS, Alibaba, Azure, Google) with 12 years experience with AWS, 10 with Azure, 8 with Google (off/on again), 1 year Alibaba.

> Which cloud is earier to learn?

How much experience in IT do you have? If you have a lot, which technologies (Linux / Open Source or Microsoft enterprise)?

Each of the clouds are excellent. Each one has very good services. Nobody is so far ahead of anyone else to really make a difference in respect to technology.

AWS is considered the market leader and tends to move faster at this time than everyone else. This also means that you will spend time every single day reading AWS blogs, product announcements, feature updates, etc. to stay current.

For your use case, any of the cloud vendors will serve you well. It is only when you have large infrastructures or very specific technical needs, that maybe one cloud is better. It really comes down to which one you prefer (or like), which one has services that you are more familiar with, which one has the support policies that you need, etc.

Another item. There is a huge race between these vendors to be the best. For any given service - `A` might be better today (or easier to use or have better tools) but tomorrow `B` is now ahead. Wait two quarters and `C` is now ahead. I expect that this will continue for another two years or so until everyone matures with their technology, services and support.

The days of only chosing one cloud vendor for everything is over. Today, I typically design three way hybrid environments (two cloud vendors and on-site data centers).